# Finding average of the column generated from sql query having group by function

Tags: mysql, function, group-by, average

I want to find the average of the following data via mysql query (assume these are 719 rows).

```
|        1 |
|        3 |
|        1 |
|        2 |
|        2 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        2 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        2 |
|        1 |
|        2 |
|        1 |
|        2 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
+----------+
719 rows in set (2.43 sec)
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM osdial_agent_log WHERE DATE(event_time)='2015-11-01' GROUP BY lead_id;
```

I ran this query to get that data

Can someone help me to find the average for the above data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT AVG(total)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM osdial_agent_log
WHERE DATE(event_time)='2015-11-01'
GROUP BY lead_id) t
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mateo but its not a field in my table its the data i fetched from the above query i mentioned

Comment: I've edited, please check (it was not clear before your edit :-) )

Comment: Cool ! Please mark your question as solved and answer as best answer so other people won't search themselves !

Comment: yeah sure ! and can you please explain what that 't' means in the end of the query.

Comment: Sure ! We're querying from results we get on the fly. It's like querying on a Table. t is the alias for the "view" we're using.
You could use **t.total** for instance.